# How to avoid that Accounts.onCreateUser overwrites users.profile?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

on the client site I have an extraSignupField -> name. This is stored in users.profile.name. Here is the code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'EMAIL_ONLY'
});

AccountsEntry.config({
  homeRoute: '/',
  dashboardRoute: '/dashboard',
  profileRoute: '/profile',
  language: 'de',
  showSignupCode: false,
  extraSignUpFields: [{
    field: "name",
    label: "Name",
    type: "text",
    required: true
  }]
 });
});
```

On the server site I run onCreateUser, this gets fired but it only sets the values which at mentioned there. NO users.profile entry is created when onCreateUser is in place.

Here is the server code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  AccountsEntry.config({
    signupCode: null
});

Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    user.username     = options.email;
    return user;
    });

});
```

My goal is to keep the data from users.profile AND the username entry. Unfortunately I got stuck at this point.

Thanks a lot 
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write your own Accounts.onCreateUser, it overrides the default.  In the default, options.profile is copied to user.profile.  You can restore default behavior by making this copy in your own version of the function.  You see this in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser).

```
Accounts.onCreateUser( function (options, user) {
    if (options.profile) user.profile = options.profile;
    user.username = options.email;
    return user;
}
```